# Combining 2 attributes with RandomForest() in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am using the function `RandomForest()` from the RandomForest package in R. I would like to be force `RandomForest()` to combine attributes.

Suppose we have the following data frame:

```
> outlook = c("sunny", "sunny", "overcast", "rain", "rain", "rain", "overcast", "sunny" , "sunny", "rain", "sunny", "overcast", "overcast", "rain")
> humidity = c("high", "high", "high", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "high")
> wind = c("weak", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "strong")
> workload = c("high", "high", "moderate", "high", "moderate", "high", "high", "moderate", "moderate", "high", "high", "moderate", "high", "moderate")
> kid_game_night = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no")
> play_tennis = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no") 
>tennis=data.frame(outlook,humidity,wind,workload,kid_game_night,play_tennis)
> tennis
    outlook humidity   wind workload kid_game_night play_tennis
1     sunny     high   weak     high             no          no
2     sunny     high strong     high             no          no
3  overcast     high   weak moderate            yes         yes
4      rain     high   weak     high            yes         yes
5      rain   normal   weak moderate             no         yes
6      rain   normal strong     high             no          no
7  overcast   normal strong     high             no         yes
8     sunny     high   weak moderate            yes          no
9     sunny   normal   weak moderate             no         yes
10     rain   normal   weak     high            yes         yes
11    sunny   normal strong     high             no         yes
12 overcast     high strong moderate             no         yes
13 overcast   normal   weak     high            yes         yes
14     rain     high strong moderate             no          no
```

In order to run `RandomForest()` with the 5 attributes outlook, humidity, wind, workload and kid_game_night one types:
  `> tennis.rf = randomForest(x=tennis[,1:5],y=as.factor(tennis$play))`

Now suppose that one wants to combine the attributes workload and kid_game_night into one single attribute (this new attribute would have 4 categories since both workload and kid_game_night have 2). Thus, instead of having `RandomForest()` consider 5 attributes with respectively 3,2,2,2, and 2 categories, have it consider 4 attributes with respectively 3,2,2 and 4 categories.
I know that I could do that by manually modifying the input dataset tennis but this is precisely what I don't want to do. Hence, my question is:
 Is there a way to compel RandomForest to combine 2 (or more) attributes *without* manually changing the input dataset tennis?

Comment: what is the issue with transforming the data in advance? you could build your dataframe by:
`data.frame(outlook,humidity,wind,as.factor(paste(workload,kid_game_night)),play_tennis)`
and then call `RandomForest()`

Comment: You could use a formula object as the input, RF takes `formula` objects, not just matrices

Comment: @DavidGo preferred to use `interaction` not `as.factor(paste(...))`

Comment: *Why* would you want to force-combine attributes? A decision tree can get the same result with two splits, so what is the benefit of hacking it this way?

Comment: @DavidGo Transforming the data in advance means saving each new version of my dataset and then loading it to R before using RandomForest(). My "real" dataset has over a million columns. It would be too slow.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I agree that a decision tree can get the same result with two splits but I am not only interested in the classification accuracy but also in the importance of each attribute. For non mathematical reasons, some of my attributes can't be considered independently but have to be considered in pairs.

Comment: Then concatenating them into one variable probably what you have to do. Or enhance the RandomForest code, because I doubt they have a function for this special case that does not improve the overall quality.